# Pass value from DropDownList to other aspx page using POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

I trying asp.net and trying posting data from one page to other. It was so easy in PHP .
I have two aspx web pages **Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx**

Page1.aspx has a drop downlist in which i select an option and on clicking submit button , this value should be passed to Page2.aspx and captured by its codebehindfile **Page2.aspx.cs** by **`Request.Form[].`**

**Page1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>  

    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="Page2.aspx">

<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server" >

<asp:ListItem value="">Select</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="1">Hello</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="2">World</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>



<asp:Button  runat="server"  />  
      </form>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

How to pass value from `Page1.aspx`? What am I doing wrong in the `form` tag? What is the alternative method?
What should I do in `Page2.aspx` to capture the selected value from the drop-down list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there are lot of difference while working on .net from PHP.
use this link for better understanding.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/asp-net-for-php-developers-part-2/

For your question change few things.

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

1) don't use the action here, we will use the button click for that.

```
<asp:button id="btnSubmit" onclick="btnSubmit_OnClick" Text="Click Me" Runat="server"></asp:button>
```

2)Change the button ,to this and create an event for button click on Page1.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.Length > 0)
{
                Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?SelectedValue=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
}
```

3) On button click check if any value is selected, If selected take the value and pass it on the second page via QueryString.

On Page2.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          string v = Request.QueryString["SelectedValue"];
     }
```

Comment: Ankur bhagwaan tujhe ati sundar bewi de..thnks bhai

Answer (score 0):

You would want to capture the user's selection and pass it along when you go to another page. Take the selected value and put it somewhere you can get to after the page transfer like the querystring or something. Then, use that days on the other end.

Comment: @user1828476 that comment made my day!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using a <select> instead of an <asp:DropDownList>. if the control is databound, you can use an <asp:Repeater> to print out the list of <option> elements

Comment: ALso, use a submit button, instead of an asp:Button.