# An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code

[IMG http://imageshack.us/a/img812/7017/98qq.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img812/7017/98qq.jpg)

When I click on Submit button in my page, I have to get dropdownlist values and I have to send it to another page.

I have followed following  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817170/pass-value-from-dropdownlist-to-other-aspx-page-using-post-method)! for that

When I try to run my code I am getting error as

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack trace:

[IMG http://imageshack.us/a/img534/9554/opdu.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img534/9554/opdu.jpg)

Can someone please tell me what is the error

Comment: Please post the stack trace as well

Comment: "using the exception stack trace below."

Comment: @NicholasV. Yes but, where is said stack trace?

Comment: I have edited my post, please see the stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace and code image links have rotted. Please post the stack trace and code as text and not as a images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than one form tags with runat="server" on your template, most probably you have one in your master page, remove one on your aspx page, it is not needed if already have form in master page file which is surrounding your content place holders.

Try to remove that tag:

```
<form id="formID" runat="server">
```

and of course closing tag:

```
</form>
```

Comment: I already have a form tag in my master page. Do I need to have another form in my CityProfilepage.aspx ?

Comment: No you don't need or even you cannot have another one if already one defined in master page (because you will have that error still)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I created a new project and when I ran it the first time, it gave me the following error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

So my solution was to go to the **Package Manager Console** inside the Visual Studio and run:**Update-Package**

Problem solved!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you have more than one form tag in your web page that causes the problem. Make sure you have only one server-side form tag for each page.